# SOLr: returning results which only if a particular field is 'undefined'

Tags: apache, solr

In solr some documents may have a particular field which is undefined for that document. I would like to know how I can return only those which have this field undefined. The field normally has a numerical value.  From what I have tried so far, using frange l=0.0, will return the documents with undefined field but will also return those which are defined as '0', which I do not want.

I have thought setting up a default value and checking for that, however the solr field in question is being set up dynamically while building indexes.  This is done by considering items in an array which exists for the current object. So if the field name is in the array for that object, the field in question will be defined with a value in solr, else it will not be defined at all.  For this reason, it is nearly impossible for me to use a default value.

Any thoughts?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can query for documents that doesn't have a specific value in a field by selecting all documents (`*:*`) and then removing those that have a value in the field:

```
q=*:* -field:[* TO *]
```

This will give you all the documents that doesn't have `field` defined.

Usually Solr will prefix pure negative queries with `*:*` internally, so just `q=-field:[* TO *]` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was now experimenting with this `-field:*` will in fact return the document with the undefined field.  Now, how can I combine this with documents which do have the field within a specific range? Was trying something like `_query_:"{!frange l=1}field" OR (-field:*)"` but only the first part seems to be working.

Comment: Refer to the first part of my answer - you have to have something to subtract it from, so your OR clause will at least have to be `OR (*:* -field:[* TO *])` since there is no implicit `*:*` added as it's not a pure negative query. You can also use `field:[1 TO *]` - there is no need for `frange` there.

Comment: that works, although I do not understand why. `*:* -field:*` and `-field:*` return the same result if on their own, why does it make a difference when in an OR ?

Comment: Because as I say in the answer; _ Usually_ Solr will prefix pure negative queries with *:* internally, so just q=-field:[* TO *] should work. When you have an `OR` statement, the query is no longer a pure negative query, and you have to explicitly say that you want to subtract the resulting set from the complete set of documents - `*:* -field:[* TO *]` (i.e. from the complete set of documents, remove those that match `[* TO *]`).